# SPX AM vs PM Reg T (T+1) Cash Settlement Dates

Tags: options, spx, settlement

Assuming I have two SPX options expiring the third Friday of a normal month with no holidays around. One (SPX) option has an AM settlement while the other (SPXW) has a PM settlement. The last trading day for the AM option is the previous Thursday, while the PM can be traded through the close of Friday.

When are the actual cash settlement (in the Reg T sense) days for both the AM and PM options and why? It seems like both are the following Monday, but wouldn't T+1 for the AM be Friday if the last trade date is Thursday?